# craigslist rss / xml /html

Tags: asp.net

I have data entry screen with Craiglist Login/pwd in aspx and I would like to capture the data and passed to craiglist screen without going to their login screen, and the data from my data entry screen will be passed/insert into Craiglist For Sales webpage....

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API for craigslist so you will have to basically use screen scraping techniques to get your data.

This question touches on some ways that you might achieve that:

- [How do craigslist mashups get data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237124/how-do-craigslist-mashups-get-data)

A great screen scraping library for .net is Html Agility Pack which is available here:

- http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

I have written some tutorials that cover using this library which might help you get started with it:

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/09/htmlagilitypack-article-series.html