# HTTP GET on craigslist blocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, craigslist

I'm trying to do a HTTP GET on craigslist [sfbay.craigslist.org](http://sfbay.craigslist.org). Here is my (ruby) code which is really simple

```
require 'net/http'
result = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://sfbay.craigslist.org'))
```

I end up getting an error "This IP has been automatically blocked."

This behaviour only happens when I try this from Amazon EC2 or on heroku. When I try again on my own computer localhost I get the correct result. Does this have to do with Amazon EC2?

I'm wondering if other people have had the same issue. What can I do to access craigslist from EC2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can confirm that Craigslist is blocking from the major Amazon EC2 IP ranges by IP (not by user agent). It works elsewhere, though I suspect any volume would cause other IPs to get blocked.

You could step around it with [tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tor). More significantly, [this stackoverflow question discusses data sources used by craigslist mashups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237124/how-do-craigslist-mashups-get-data).

I even tested a Brazil EC2, assuming they might not have all the CIDRs blocked. No bueno.

Comment: Isn't this unethical? It is clearly not blocking Google or Bing or of course, Yahoo!