# Heroku throws OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, http-status-code-403, open-uri

I have a Rails 4 Application serving up JSON data to a BackboneJS frontend client.  The backend scrapes some content from Craigslist and serves it to the frontend as JSON.  Locally, in development, it works just as expected.

On Heroku, the application layout does get served correctly and assets seem to load just fine.  It isn't until backboneJS queries for data to fill the appropriate view, and there the app fails due to the OpenURI error.

More specifically, OpenURI keeps returning the

```
OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden)
```

when executing the following line in the Rails controller:

```
open( "#{clist.url}" )
```

I have spent several hours trying various 'solved' solutions I have found on Stack Overflow and Github and just trying to look through the Heroku logs for other errors, but the error remains no matter which suggested 'solutions' I try out.

As of now, I have tried the following suggested solutions, along with several other silly ones:

- Required open-uri in my application controller
- Added the 'User-Agent' key to my open method call
- Changed the clist.url from "https" to "http" to avoid redirects

Also, the app is straight forward and doesn't require authentication at the moment either.

Apart from Stack Overflow and github, I couldn't find any suggested solutions elsewhere.  Any help with any suggestions on other debugging tips to try or suggested solutions would be extremely appreciated.  I am fairly new to Heroku, so still getting acquainted with debugging issues like this on a remote production engine.

Here is the relevant code that fetches from Craigslist (don't judge me too harshly.  All/Most of this method is set to be refactored and put into it's own Class/Model, which is where it belongs ):

```
def index
    @listings = []

    #Retrieve job listings from Craigslist (see method sync_list below ... )
    @raw_listings = sync_clist

    # filters applied at this point ...
    # and they transform @raw_listings to ...
    # the array @listings

    render json: @listings
end

def sync_clist
    #@search_items = SearchItem.all
    @search_items = SearchItem.all[0..1]
    site = @sites[0]

    # in the Craigslist HTML, the second element in the returned job listing # is the better one to use
    href_idx = 1

    ##### LINE 123 is the next one:
    @search_items.each_with_index do |search_item, idx|
      puts "#{search_item.url.upcase}"

      ##### LINE 125 ... FAILURE_HERE? ***************** 
      html = open( "#{search_item.url}", 'User-Agent' => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
      page = Nokogiri::HTML( html.read, nil, 'utf-8' )
      category_idx = idx % 4
      isNearby_listing = false     #also capture 'nearby' jobs on Craigslist

      page.css( site[:joblist_css] )[0..-2].each_with_index do |listing, i|
        # convert the relative url in the list to a full-url
        locale_idx = idx/@clist_locales.length
        listing_url = listing.css('a')[href_idx]['href']

        # Craigslist only lists the relative path of job urls - relative to the
        # current search location. The 'More Local' items, however, return the
        # full url.
        if !isNearby_listing
          posting_url = site[:protocol] + site[:locales][locale_idx] + "." + site[:host] + listing_url
        else
          posting_url = listing_url
        end

        # Once the appropriate heading is reached, the 'More Local' listings
        # items begin appearing
        if listing.next_sibling.node_name == 'h4'
          isNearby_listing = true
        end

        posting_date = listing.css('time')[0]['datetime']
        job_listing = { :source       => site[:sitename].upcase,
                        :title        => listing.css('a')[href_idx].text,
                        :url          => posting_url,
                        :listing_id   => listing["data-pid"],
                        :location     => @clist_locales[locale_idx],
                        :content      => "",
                        :telecommute  => "",
                        :contract     => "",
                        :pt_ft        => "",
                        :favorite     => false,
                        :posted_date  => posting_date,
                        :category     => @clist_categories[category_idx],
                        :apply_state  => "new"
        }

        @new_listings << job_listing
      end
    end
    @new_listings
  end
```

Here is the output of my Heroku logs in case it helps:

```

```
2015-04-27T03:47:14.611278+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43688
2015-04-27T03:47:14.611280+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-04-27T03:47:14.611310+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.5.106.52 at 2015-04-27 03:47:14 +0000
2015-04-27T03:47:14.611272+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-04-27T03:47:14.611281+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-04-27T03:47:14.664777+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered app/root.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2015-04-27T03:47:14.661735+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AppController#root as HTML
2015-04-27T03:47:14.664783+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered app/root.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2015-04-27T03:47:14.674604+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 12.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-04-27T03:47:14.674612+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 12.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-04-27T03:47:14.611302+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 24.5.106.52 at 2015-04-27 03:47:14 +0000
2015-04-27T03:47:14.661749+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AppController#root as HTML
2015-04-27T03:47:15.943141+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-45c34fbd86efe641e061caa3b34737d7.css" host=APPNAME.herokuapp.com request_id=dbf8473e-2880-42f6-8ef4-11e0da7141b4 fwd="24.5.106.52" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=73ms status=200 bytes=569692
2015-04-27T03:47:15.944069+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-537f60efd0378faaddaea08875f25055.js" host=APPNAME.herokuapp.com request_id=5c7cf6db-393f-434e-a494-d3664d31a20f fwd="24.5.106.52" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=70ms status=200 bytes=965489
2015-04-27T03:47:17.631614+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/posts" for 24.5.106.52 at 2015-04-27 03:47:17 +0000
2015-04-27T03:47:17.631624+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/posts" for 24.5.106.52 at 2015-04-27 03:47:17 +0000
2015-04-27T03:47:17.636842+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#index as JSON
2015-04-27T03:47:17.636831+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#index as JSON
2015-04-27T03:47:17.665568+00:00 app[web.1]: HTTP://SFBAY.CRAIGSLIST.ORG/SEARCH/SOF?QUERY=RAILS
2015-04-27T03:47:18.048174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=APPNAME.herokuapp.com request_id=a2724fb9-6872-4435-8dfc-0df1b73fb761 fwd="24.5.106.52" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=417ms status=500 bytes=330
2015-04-27T03:47:18.042116+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 405ms
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043586+00:00 app[web.1]: OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):
2015-04-27T03:47:18.042129+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 405ms
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043590+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:123:in `each'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043588+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:125:in `block in sync_clist'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043593+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:123:in `sync_clist'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043584+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043591+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:123:in `each_with_index'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043596+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043594+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:53:in `index'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043597+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043602+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043604+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:125:in `block in sync_clist'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043603+00:00 app[web.1]: OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043606+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:123:in `each'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043607+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:123:in `each_with_index'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043610+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:53:in `index'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043609+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:123:in `sync_clist'
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043613+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-04-27T03:47:18.043611+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

```

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. Can you edit your question and add any snippets of relevant code? eg your 500 error in the logs references posts_controller 's index action... which means it'd be where I'd start to look.

Comment: Also, just checking: `host=APPNAME.herokuapp.com ` is that deliberate obfuscation on your part (which is fine btw), or have you accidentally literally got `APPNAME` in there? :)

Comment: APPNAME is an obfuscation.  I'll add the relevant controller code in a second.

Comment: So is it the `SearchItem.all` line that it's breaking on in posts_controller? (if so,can you give us the relevant parts of the code in `SearchItem`) (if not can you give us an indication of which line it is - to match against the stacktrace)

Comment: I added a comment on where the failure occurs.  In essence the code above shows that:  1) controller :index calls method sync_list.  2) I added a 'FAILS_HERE' comment above the line in 'sync_list' where the failure occurs.  3) the SearchItem is just an object that besides other attributes, also contains a url attribute (in this case "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sof?query=rails" ... see the log) which is converted to a string and passed into the open-uri 'open' method which is where the failure occurs.

Comment: yes... but on which line of `sync_clist` is the error occurring? according to the stacktrace, it's on line 123 or line 125 of your posts_controller.rb ... if that line is the one that is `@search_items = SearchItem.all[0..1]` then we can narrow it down to being a problem with `SearchItem.all[0..1]` - if it isn't, the i need to know which line it is...

Comment: OK, my apologies.  I added comments just above lines 123 and 125.  I probably should have linked it to begin with, so if it helps, the app repo is here:  [The App github repo](https://github.com/jose8a/yojobs)  and the relevant controller is here: [Posts Controller](https://github.com/jose8a/yojobs/blob/master/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb)

Comment: cool thanks - yeah, so now I see where you're coming from. Have you tested whether you can actually get to that URL eg with curl ? have you tried getting to it manually in the rails console?

Comment: you mean locally?  The app works locally just fine and open-uri fetches from Craigslist just as it should.  It only fails on Heroku.

Comment: ah right... darn. That does make it harder :P

Comment: hmmm. do you know you can `heroku run rails c --app APPNAME` ? :)

Comment: not sure what that does for me.  Can you clarify why I should do that?

Comment: you can then test it manually in a rails console... on heroku. Not sure it'll solve your problem, but you can play with the connection more directly.

Comment: @Taryn - Thanks for the suggestion.  At least it led to an explanation for why the app works locally and not on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @TarynEast's suggestion and running app code in the Heroku console, I switched to using the 'net/http' library instead of 'open-uri' to retrieve the Craigslist webpage.  The following message was returned by Craigslist when using 'net/http':

```
"This IP has been automatically blocked.\nIf you have questions, please email: blocks-b1402369961264436@craigslist.org\n"
```

So, apparently, either all of Heroku IPs have been blocked, or, more likely, it's just my app specifically that has been blocked even though my app only pings craigslist at most 8 times per site load.  Maybe that was enough to block it since Craigslist is a very popular target of scraping apps.  Anyways, mystery solved as to why the 403 Error.  At least app still works locally.

[Update:] According to a quick Google search, Craigslist blocks the entirety of AWS and Heroku IPs, amongst others.  See SO question here: [Craigslist blocking Heroku/AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328955/http-get-on-craigslist-blocked)

Comment: @juan8a Did you find any other way of scraping Craigslist?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk - from what I could tell, you can scrape it as long as the IP of the server doing the scraping hasn't been banned already (e.g. your local machine).  All of Heroku  and AWS (probably Google Cloud, Digital Ocean, Microsoft's cloud, etc) are all banned AFAIK ... but your local IP should be fine as long as Craigslist hasn't flagged you already for abuse.  Check their user guidelines to make sure you're not running afoul of their 'rules of use'.

Comment: @juan8a I know that, since I've done a bit of scraping locally. Don't wanna get my own IP banned though, so do you know any other services that hasn't been banned?!

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk you'll have to do your own searching to find that out.  It's been a while since I checked on this and what I found then is the services I was interested in using (AWS and Heroku, primarily) were already banned.  Once I found that out, I didn't really look elsewhere.  I'm OK with keeping the service on my personal machine since I didn't plan on launching a service for others to use.

Comment: @juan8a And Reddit didn't ban you? For how long did you do it? Approximately how many pages a day did you hit?!

Comment: Reddit?.  Anyways, I was building an app to help me automate and filter job listings for my own job search and for side gigs.  I probably had the app check the site (3 or 4 pages) at most a couple times a day.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I had a Rails app hosted on Heroku opening a file held on S3. I got the same error because the URL was wrong.